# Angular form error Property does not exist on type

Tags: angular

I created this simple form form1.component.html in Angular

```
    <form #personForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(personForm)" novalidate>
        <div>
            <label> Enter First Name </label>
            <input 
            type="text"
            [(ngModel)]="person.firstName"
            required
            pattern="[A-Za-z]*"
            #firstName="ngModel"
            name="fName"
            />            
        </div>


      <div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn-solid">Submit</button>
        <button type="button" (click)="clearForm(personForm)">Reset</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

The ts file form1.component.ts is as follows

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form1',
  templateUrl: './form1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form1.component.css']
})
export class Form1Component implements OnInit {
  person!: {};

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.person = {
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Black'
    };

  }
  submitForm = (form: any) => {
  }

  clearForm = (form: any) => {
    form.reset();
    form.submitted = false;
  }
}
```

When I run ng serve in VS Code, I get following error

```
Error: src/app/components/form1/form1.component.html:6:33 - error TS2339: Property 'firstName' does not exist on type '{}'.

6             [(ngModel)]="person.firstName"
                                  ~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/components/form1/form1.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './form1.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component Form1Component.
```

I tried to initialize the person class in constructor, but still gives the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a wrong type declaration

Change the declared type in your component

```
export class Form1Component implements OnInit {
  person!: { firstName: string; lastName: string };
```

Otherwise you can make it even more lighter by

```
 export class Form1Component implements OnInit {
      person!: any;
```

Also if you don't want to duplicate your code of `{ firstName: string; lastName: string }` create an interface type

```
interface Person{
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}
```

and then you can use it in multiple places like

```
export class Form1Component implements OnInit {
  person!: Person;

  doSomething(person: Person) {

  ...
  }
```

Comment: Don't use `any`! That's basically throwing away all Typescript benefit!

Answer (score 0):

While the form is incomplete (since it only has first name) you can declare an interface to use throughout your component. This will give you better type security instead of having `any` scattered through the component.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

interface Person{
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form1',
  templateUrl: './form1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form1.component.css']
})
export class Form1Component implements OnInit {
  person: Person;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.person = {
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Black'
    };

  }
  submitForm = (form: NgForm) => {
    this.person = form.value as Person;
  }

  clearForm = (form: NgForm) => {
    form.reset();
    form.submitted = false;
  }
}
```